# Data validation package for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html, validation, forms

Stupid question.

I've got a project that I'm working on in PHP; it's a registration form for a customer that will eventually write to a MySQL database. I've got the form doing data validation for the fields involved, and I'm already using some of PHP's builtin [filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php).

However, I've got quite a few fields that I need to validate for different purposes - for example, I've got email addresses and web addresses to verify (which are covered in the filter package), but I've also got to verify phone numbers, zip codes, addresses, and names (which should only match a certain character set).

Right now, my solution consists of a lot of if-then statements to verify a field. For instance, for zipcode, I verify whether it's numeric with ctype_digit, and then I use strlen to check the length. (I could encapsulate everything inside an object - and I will probably do so once I've got everything working as it actually should - but that's a little ways away.) Does anyone know of a third-party class that will do stuff like this? Or, if not, at least a way to validate specific input types without resorting to if statements based on the input name. since it's really not scalable?

If I ned to edit this question or add anything, let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php). It lets you do your own custom validations.

```
$filter_zip_options = array( "options" => array( "regexp" => "/^[0-9]{5}$/" ) );
var_dump( (bool)filter_var( "99999", FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, $filter_zip_options ) ); //bool(true)
var_dump( (bool)filter_var( "991999", FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, $filter_zip_options ) ); //bool(false)
```

If you hate regex, you can also use [`FILTER_CALLBACK`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php).

```
//To use a closure as an in place callback you need PHP 5.3
var_dump( filter_var( "Kendall", FILTER_CALLBACK, array( "options" => function( $input ) {
    //check if it's 1 or 2 words
    if( count( explode( " ", $input ) ) > 2 )
        return FALSE;

    return "Hello world $input";
} ) ) );
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been using the filter functions already. Unfortunately, that doesn't get me away from the if/then statements. I guess this is the best I'll get, though. At some point, I'll just have to write a form object that will take multiple arguments - like whether the field is required, what type of data should be entered, field name, etc.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 I'm not sure of what if/then logic your talking about. You can validate length and since all $_POST/$_GET values are strings there isn't much else that a regex can't validate. Maybe you could provide an example of some of your if/then logic your trying to remove? – Kendall Hopkins 8 secs ago edit

Comment: Nah, it's really just the error stuff. `if (!condition) then error['field1'] = "blah blah blah"`, which I have to do for every field since I need to print specific error messages for form users. Additionally, some fields are required and some are not, leading to yet more checking. There just doesn't seem to be a quick way to genericize it and abstract it out at the moment.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 I did it by making a wrapping function, so I could do `$input = required_inputs( array( "input1" => *filter_var stuff*, ... ) ) + optional_inputs( array( "opt_input1" => *filter_var stuff*, ... ) );`. `required_input` would throw an exception if an input didn't exists or was malformed, and `optional_input` would just return NULL in those cases. This provides a known set of keys that are always defined and I've found greatly reduced the needed if/else logic.

Comment: @ Kendall Yeah, that's my next solution, once I get the basics working for this customer. Without an object of some sort, data validation and error printing is PHP forms is really tedious.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/php/37-tested-php-perl-and-javascript-regular-expressions) link might help you, it contains the most common regular expressions which can be used to validate user input. It's not a good idea to validate fields on the client side (javascript) you should never trust your users.

Comment: I don't. I always assume that a) users are stupid and b) users are malicious. Makes my life harder, but makes everyone else's lives easier.

Answer (score -7):

I give you a clue.. in php .. don't use the OOP programming.. if you use database (and you're forced to) just encapsulate your data in an array or something like that.

Secondly, for validation. You might use regular expression to confirm your fields. However, if you know javascript, use some `alert()` for it.

Good luck :D

Comment: -1 How does `alert()` have anything to with __form validation__ in __PHP__?

Comment: That still doesn't absolve you of doing *real validation on the server*.

Comment: Also, *no OOP*? You might want to qualify that statement.

Comment: Hate to downvote, but there are a lot of things wrong with this answer. Javascript isn't foolproof, especially since it's optional. Although I may implement Javascript at some point, I need PHP validation to protect my data first.